# Como adaptar esta função para funcionar sem precisar do ID do elemento?

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Tenho uma função e quero adaptá-la para funcionar sem precisar do ID do elemento (`document.getElementById("slides");`). Vi que existe a possibilidade de fazer isso usando o operador `NEW` porém tive dificuldades. Tem algum exemplo prático que possa ajudar?

```
pg      = 0;
sg      = 20000;
ft      = document.getElementById("slides");
sn      = ft.getElementsByTagName("div");
tt      = sn.length-1;
st      = ["content-slide show-slide", "content-slide"];

//onclick
function slide(i){"proximo"==i&&md_n(),"anterior"==i&&md_p()}

//próximo
function  md_n(){
    if(pg < tt){
        pg=pg+1;
        sn.item(pg).setAttribute("class", st[0]);
        if(pg > 0){
            sn.item(pg-1).setAttribute("class", st[1]);
        }
    }else if(pg > 0 && pg == tt){
        pg=0;
        sn.item(pg).setAttribute("class", st[0]);
        sn.item(tt).setAttribute("class", st[1]);
    }
    console.log("slide: "+pg);
}

//anterior
function md_p(){
    if(pg > 0){
        pg=pg-1;
        sn.item(pg).setAttribute("class", st[0]);
        if(pg > -1){
            sn.item(pg+1).setAttribute("class", st[1]);
        }
    }else if(pg > -1 && pg != tt){
        pg=sn.length-1;
        sn.item(pg).setAttribute("class", st[0]);
        sn.item(pg-(tt)).setAttribute("class", st[1]);
    }
    console.log("slide: "+pg);
}
//play
start = setInterval(function(){md_n()}, sg);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem o id, uma opção é buscar pela propriedade class. `document.getElementsByClassName("nome_da_class");`.

Note que isso retorna um array, independente de encontrar um único elemento.

Exemplo

```
var e = document.getElementsByClassName("nome_da_class");
console.log(e[0]); // imprime no console o primeiro que encontrou.
```

Para ter todos que encontrou, faça uma laço de repetição

```
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    console.log(e[i]);
}
```

De outra forma teria que ler o documento inteiro por todos os documentos até encontrar propriedades específicas do elemento que procura como nome da tag, largura, altura, etc.

Esteja ciente de que postei apenas exemplos, sem tratamento de erros. Por exemplo, no mínimo deve verificar se algo foi encontrado, se não retornou falso, nulo ou undefined, enfim.

Answer (score 1):

Desta maneira pode selecionar elementos com os seletores normais css.

[querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) devolve um elemento (o primeiro que encontrar), ou nenhum (caso não haja um elemento com a propriedade desejada)

Já [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) devolve todos os elementos (array) com a propriedade desejada, caso existam

```js
var heyClass = document.querySelectorAll('.hey')[0]; // primeiro elemento
var heyData = document.querySelector('[data-name="yoo"]'); // primeiro elemento
var spanTag = document.querySelectorAll('span')[0]; // primeiro elemento

console.log(heyClass);
console.log(heyData);
console.log(spanTag);
```

```html
<div class="hey"></div>
<div data-name="yoo"></div>
<span></span>
```

Comment: O problema de eu selecionar os elementos pela classe é que desta forma geraria conflito caso eu tentasse implementar mais de um slide por página

Comment: Editado em cima, pode dar os atributos que quiser, nesse caso use querySelectorAll(), como demonstro em cima. Desta maneira consegue obter todos os slides da página. Expliquei em baixo como funciona

Comment: Perfeita a explicação Migue, porém note que ao implementar dois "Slides"  na página não é possível eu usar a mesma função, conforme no exemplo a seguir: -> https://jsbin.com/zihosivexo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Tem de fazer um ciclo for para percorrer todos os slides: http://jsfiddle.net/4huzr/2676/ . Tente implentar assim com está no inicio do js

Comment: Mesmo dessa forma ainda não deu certo: https://jsbin.com/zihosivexo/edit?html,js,output